# Javascript array object replace data with regexp

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have object array like this:

```
test = [",postContent", ",All", ",true", ",270", ",360", ",true", ",true", 
        ",true", ",undefined", ",undefined", ",undefined", ",undefined",
        ",true", ",true", ",302612", ",2668", ",185", ",292", ",6433",
        ",1846", ",843", ",3272", ",4458", ",2069", ",642", ",20", ",5",
        ",25", ",20", ",6", ",101", ",19", ",66", ",44", ",true", ",true",
        ",true", ",true", ",true", ",true", ",true", ""];
```

As you can see it's object array and I can't use `test.replace(regexp)`

How can I replace all commas after `"` in this case, with object array?

Comment: I modified a bit your code because it was invalid. Feel free to edit it if I did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
test = test.map(function(item){
    return item.replace(/^,/, '');
});
```

Or, assuming all entries begin with `,` or are the empty string, this should be faster

```js
test = test.map(function(item){
    return item.substr(1);
});
```

Comment: @qqqdddqqq I forgot `)`.

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
test = test.join("-").replace(",","").split("-");
```

Keep in mind that your texts may not contain '-' characters for it to work.
You can replace the two "-" with a delimiter variable thats sufficiently complex.

`test.join("-")` converts the array test to the string `",postContent-,All-,true..."`, 
`.replace(",","")` will replace commas in the string with empty character so the string will be `"postContent-All-true..."` and finally `.split("-")` will convert the last string to the array `["postContent", "All", "true", ...]` Thus producing the desired output.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat short. Could you explain what it does?

Comment: test.join("-") converts the array test to the string ",postContent-,All-,true..." then .replace(",","") will replace commas in the string with empty character so the string will be "postContent-All-true..." and finally .split("-") will convert the last string to the array ["postContent", "All", "true", ...]